# How can I make various strings and shuffle them randomly

Tags: swift, random

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped() {
    //I figured out how to put random numbers but I want to put random words that I write
    var randomText = String(arc4random_uniform(5))  

    textLabel.setText(randomText)             
}
```

Basically instead of having random numbers being displayed when button is tapped, I want random strings to display. For example ["yes", "no", maybe"] randomly appearing instead of numbers 0-5.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array of all of the strings you want to possibly display, then generate a random number between 0 and the array count (minus 1 for the index), then use that random number to get a string from the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
func getRandomString()->String{
    let sArray = ["Yes","No","Maybe","Like","Ok"] //can have any number of words
    let count = UInt32(sArray.count)
    let randNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(count))
    return sArray[randNumber]
}

println(getRandomString())
```

Comment: Do I put that where the "randomText" is? right here: textLabel.setText(randomText)

Comment: textLabel.setText(getRandomString())